# IDE's for C# development on Linux?

Tags: c#, linux, ide, mono

What are my options?  I tried MonoDevelop over a year ago but it was extremely buggy.  Is the latest version a stable development environment?

Comment: I don't want to be a total downer, but have you downloaded it and given it a try? With the plethora of free ways to run linux for free on your machine, I hope you can come back and answer this question

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Yes, I have a stable Linux installation.
Yes, I have tried an older version of MonoDevelop (as I indicated in the question)

Are you asking if I have tried every available C# compatible IDE?

Comment: You could download the latest build and try it again....a year is a long time.

Comment: I'm asking about what SO recommends, not just MonoDevelop, and it's not very wise to start a project only to find out a few weeks later that the IDE doesn't support X,Y,Z or that it crashes when you use a certain construct.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

MonoDevelop 2.0 has been released, it now has a decent GUI Debugger, code completion, Intellisense C# 3.0 support (including linq), and a decent GTK# Visual Designer.

In short, since the 2.0 release I have started using Mono Develop again and am very happy with it so far.

Check out the [MonoDevelop website](http://monodevelop.com/) for more info.

Comment: MonoDevelop 4.0 is now available. I use VS2012 regularly, and this is an amazing contender given that its Linux/Opensource (VisualStudio, unlike everything else MS, rocks).

Comment: Can I use it to develop mobile apps for Android and iPhone?

Comment: @AaronFranke no, Xamarin Studio is required for android/ios dev. Xamarin Studio is Mono Develop + Android and IOS and Xamarin/Microsoft has chosen not to support Xamarin Studio on linux

Answer (score 18):

Microsoft has released [Visual Studio Code](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/code-vs.aspx) for Linux, which has good C# support, naturally.

Comment: Can I use it to develop mobile apps for Android and iPhone?

Comment: There are extensions, such as Cordova that make mobile development possible. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/03/30/build-ionic-apps-in-minutes-with-vs-code/

Comment: Mind that the C# debugger for VS Code is not open source. There are [ways](https://github.com/VSCodium/vscodium/issues/82#issue-409806641) to use a different debugger.

Answer (score 8):

**Monodevelop**
There are 2 versions around:

- 1.0: the currently stable version. It is indeed stable, but somewhat limited in its capabilities. It's very good for smallish projects. I got it via the ubuntu hardy repos.
- 2.0RC (aka 1.9.x) you can get it via SVN and compiling. The process is quite straightforward, and you can run it without installing (via `make run`). It's somewhat less stable than 1.0, but it depends on which build you get (it's a development snapshot). Regarding capabilities, it is great. It has refactoring, profiling, tons of plugins, etc.

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend X-develop from [Omnicore](http://www.omnicore.com). It is a very good IDE, but is only free to use for 30 days.

Comment: That looks pretty good if it works as well as advertized. Thx for the link.

Comment: Works well. And there's a way around the 30 day limit - just delete the files and directories it creates in your home dir.

Comment: nice way to avoid paying the developers for their work.

Comment: That link is dead. I think this might be the new link: http://freecode.com/projects/xdevelop

Comment: That link is still dead. Also, that "freecode.com" site is discontinued.

Answer (score 4):

There is a C# binding for Eclipse, though I haven't tried it personally, so I can't vouch for it.  I use MonoDevelop, which isn't perfect, but works reasonably well for the most part.  The version included in Ubuntu 8.04 (Hardy Heron) is much more stable than the Gutsy Gibbon version.

Comment: I believe the C# bindings for eclipse are not maintained anymore and were not that good anyways.

Answer (score 4):

I've been using [JetBrains Rider](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider) for quite a while and I quite like it.

It has all the ReSharper goodness and is a joy to use on OS/X or Linux. Beware that it is still in Early Access Program, so it has a few rough edges there and there, but most of the times it works well enough for day-to-day usage.

You can get it here:
https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/download/

P.S. I mostly use it for .NET Core development needs, but have used it for traditional .NET coding as well.

Answer (score 3):

I used MonoDevelop a while ago, and it was fine. It's not anywhere near as good as Eclipse or NetBeans are for Java development, but those are really in a class of their own. And I think the only real alternative is using emacs or vim...

It's fairly polished. Stability really wasn't an issue. Simple code-completion is there, as is jumping to to declaration, super-class and the extremely useful find references. Debugging isn't there, though, which is a fairly glaring omission. I actually spent a couple of minutes trying to set up a breakpoint until it dawned on me that there isn't even a way to "Debug..." instead of "Run..."

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at [SlickEdit](http://www.slickedit.com/)?  I thought it was pretty good several years ago when I was developing C++ apps on Linux.  It says it supports C#, but I cannot comment as to how well.  I was happy to use it for my C++ development, though.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the latest version stable a stable development environment?

Probably ... it hit 1.0 this past spring.